# Magento1 - Getting Notice and error relating to GeoIP in system.log

Tags: magento-1.9, system.log, geoip

I'm getting below Notice and error in system.log file continuously :

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0  in /lib/GeoIP/geoip.inc on line 413
2019-06-26T05:26:23+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1  in /lib/GeoIP/geoip.inc on line 413
2019-06-26T05:26:23+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 2  in /lib/GeoIP/geoip.inc on line 413
2019-06-26T05:26:23+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 3  in /lib/GeoIP/geoip.inc on line 413
2019-06-26T05:26:23+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 4  in /lib/GeoIP/geoip.inc on line 413
2019-06-26T05:26:23+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 5  in /lib/GeoIP/geoip.inc on line 413
2019-06-26T05:26:23+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: error traversing database - perhaps it is corrupt?  in /lib/GeoIP/geoip.inc on line 428
```

Where should I check for this?